# Not able to move from one activity to another

Tags: android-studio, android-activity, onclick

User registration works within the signup activity, however the login activity refuses to move to next activity - no matter what I try.

Logcat wih beginning of crash
--------- beginning of crash
2020-10-05 13:44:28.902 23498-23555/com.example.doadventuresv30 V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2020-10-05 13:44:29.123 23696-23724/com.example.doadventuresv30 V/FA: onActivityCreated
2020-10-05 13:44:29.140 23696-23743/com.example.doadventuresv30 V/FA: App measurement collection enabled
2020-10-05 13:44:29.141 23696-23743/com.example.doadventuresv30 V/FA: App measurement enabled for app package, google app id: com.example.doadventuresv30, 1:715052012741:android:8d25e7726c2397e69b4cac
2020-10-05 13:44:29.142 23696-23743/com.example.doadventuresv30 I/FA: App measurement initialized, version: 31049
2020-10-05 13:44:29.142 23696-23743/com.example.doadventuresv30 I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
2020-10-05 13:44:29.142 23696-23743/com.example.doadventuresv30 I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.example.doadventuresv30
2020-10-05 13:44:29.142 23696-23743/com.example.doadventuresv30 D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
2020-10-05 13:44:29.177 23696-23743/com.example.doadventuresv30 V/FA: Connecting to remote service
2020-10-05 13:44:29.190 23696-23743/com.example.doadventuresv30 V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2020-10-05 13:44:29.199 23696-23743/com.example.doadventuresv30 V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2020-10-05 13:44:29.200 23696-23743/com.example.doadventuresv30 V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 1176833846
2020-10-05 13:44:29.214 23696-23743/com.example.doadventuresv30 I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
2020-10-05 13:44:29.234 23696-23743/com.example.doadventuresv30 V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2020-10-05 13:44:29.235 23696-23743/com.example.doadventuresv30 V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2020-10-05 13:44:29.237 23696-23743/com.example.doadventuresv30 V/FA: Screen exposed for less than 1000 ms. Event not sent. time: 12
2020-10-05 13:44:29.237 23696-23743/com.example.doadventuresv30 V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2020-10-05 13:44:29.237 23696-23743/com.example.doadventuresv30 V/FA: Activity paused, time: 1176833860
2020-10-05 13:44:29.260 23696-23724/com.example.doadventuresv30 V/FA: onActivityCreated
2020-10-05 13:44:29.294 23696-23743/com.example.doadventuresv30 V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 1176833952
2020-10-05 13:44:29.325 23696-23743/com.example.doadventuresv30 V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2020-10-05 13:44:29.325 23696-23743/com.example.doadventuresv30 V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2020-10-05 13:44:29.337 23696-23743/com.example.doadventuresv30 D/FA: Connected to remote service
2020-10-05 13:44:29.338 23696-23743/com.example.doadventuresv30 V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 8
2020-10-05 13:44:29.359 31341-22371/? V/FA-SVC: Logging event: origin=auto,name=user_engagement(_e),params=Bundle[{ga_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=13025, ga_screen_class(_sc)=LoginActivity, ga_screen_id(_si)=-7054614402516150973}]
2020-10-05 13:44:29.365 31341-22371/? V/FA-SVC: Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 3361930
2020-10-05 13:44:29.365 31341-22371/? V/FA-SVC: Unscheduling upload
2020-10-05 13:44:29.367 31341-22371/? V/FA-SVC: Scheduling upload, millis: 3361930
2020-10-05 13:44:29.373 31341-22371/? V/FA-SVC: Background event processing time, ms: 14
2020-10-05 13:44:29.376 31341-22371/? V/FA-SVC: Logging event: origin=auto,name=screen_view(_vs),params=Bundle[{ga_event_origin(_o)=auto, ga_previous_class(_pc)=LoginActivity, ga_previous_id(_pi)=-7054614402516150973, ga_screen_class(_sc)=FeatureDashboardNewsDashboard1Activity, ga_screen_id(_si)=-7054614402516150972}]
2020-10-05 13:44:29.380 31341-22371/? V/FA-SVC: Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 3361915
2020-10-05 13:44:29.380 31341-22371/? V/FA-SVC: Unscheduling upload
2020-10-05 13:44:29.381 31341-22371/? V/FA-SVC: Scheduling upload, millis: 3361915
2020-10-05 13:44:29.384 31341-22371/? V/FA-SVC: Background event processing time, ms: 8
2020-10-05 13:44:29.387 31341-22371/? V/FA-SVC: Logging event: origin=auto,name=screen_view(_vs),params=Bundle[{ga_event_origin(_o)=auto, ga_screen_class(_sc)=SplashActivity, ga_screen_id(_si)=-7054614402516150975}]
2020-10-05 13:44:29.391 31341-22371/? V/FA-SVC: Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 3361904
2020-10-05 13:44:29.391 31341-22371/? V/FA-SVC: Unscheduling upload
2020-10-05 13:44:29.393 31341-22371/? V/FA-SVC: Scheduling upload, millis: 3361904
2020-10-05 13:44:29.395 31341-22371/? V/FA-SVC: Background event processing time, ms: 8
2020-10-05 13:44:29.397 31341-22371/? V/FA-SVC: Logging event: origin=auto,name=screen_view(_vs),params=Bundle[{ga_event_origin(_o)=auto, ga_previous_class(_pc)=SplashActivity, ga_previous_id(_pi)=-7054614402516150975, ga_screen_class(_sc)=SplashActivityLayout, ga_screen_id(_si)=-187945021663330027}]
2020-10-05 13:44:29.402 31341-22371/? V/FA-SVC: Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 3361893
2020-10-05 13:44:29.402 31341-22371/? V/FA-SVC: Unscheduling upload
2020-10-05 13:44:29.404 31341-22371/? V/FA-SVC: Scheduling upload, millis: 3361893
2020-10-05 13:44:29.406 31341-22371/? V/FA-SVC: Background event processing time, ms: 9
2020-10-05 13:44:29.411 31341-22371/? V/FA-SVC: Saving default event parameters, appId, data size: com.example.doadventuresv30, 2
2020-10-05 13:44:34.424 23696-23743/com.example.doadventuresv30 V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
2020-10-05 13:44:40.323 1269-11445/? D/Telecom-CreateConnectionProcessor: CreateConnectionProcessor created for Call = [TC@87, NEW, null, xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, A, childs(0), has_parent(false), [Capabilities:], [Properties:]]
2020-10-05 13:44:40.328 1269-11445/? D/Telecom-CreateConnectionProcessor: attemptNextPhoneAccount
2020-10-05 13:44:40.328 1269-11445/? I/Telecom-CreateConnectionProcessor: Trying attempt CallAttemptRecord(ComponentInfo{com.android.phone/com.android.services.telephony.TelephonyConnectionService}, ***, UserHandle{0},ComponentInfo{com.android.phone/com.android.services.telephony.TelephonyConnectionService}, ***, UserHandle{0})
2020-10-05 13:44:40.329 1269-11445/? D/Telecom-ConnectionServiceWrapper: cmcc encryption call is not enabled, return.
2020-10-05 13:44:40.330 1269-11445/? D/Telecom-ConnectionServiceWrapper: createConnection([TC@87, NEW, com.android.phone/com.android.services.telephony.TelephonyConnectionService, xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, A, childs(0), has_parent(false), [Capabilities:], [Properties:]]) via ComponentInfo{com.android.phone/com.android.services.telephony.TelephonyConnectionService}.
2020-10-05 13:44:40.352 1269-1269/? D/Telecom-ConnectionServiceWrapper: Telecom -> ConnectionService[com.android.phone/com.android.services.telephony.TelephonyConnectionService]: addConnectionServiceAdapter com.android.server.telecom.ConnectionServiceWrapper$Adapter@df1b213
2020-10-05 13:44:40.354 1269-11445/? D/Telecom-ConnectionServiceWrapper: ConnectionService -> Telecom[com.android.phone/com.android.services.telephony.TelephonyConnectionService]: queryRemoteConnectionServices callingPackage=com.android.phone
2020-10-05 13:44:40.360 1269-11445/? D/Telecom-ConnectionServiceWrapper: queryRemoteConnectionServices: none; not sim call mgr.
2020-10-05 13:44:40.361 2686-2686/? I/Telephony-TelephonyConnectionService: onCreateIncomingConnection

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

```
TextView createTextView;
LinearLayout facebookLinearLayout, twitterLinearLayout, googlePlusLinearLayout;
Button loginButton, forgotButton;
ImageView bgImageView;
EditText emEmail, emPassword;
FirebaseAuth mAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    initUI();
    initDataBindings();
    initActions();
    emEmail = findViewById(R.id.emEmail);
    emPassword = findViewById(R.id.emPassword);
    findViewById(R.id.createTextView).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.loginButton).setOnClickListener(this);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
}

//region Init Functions
private void initUI() {
    forgotButton = findViewById(R.id.forgotButton);
    createTextView = findViewById(R.id.createTextView);

    facebookLinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.facebookLinearLayout);
    twitterLinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.twitterLinearLayout);
    googlePlusLinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.googlePlusLinearLayout);

    loginButton = findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
    bgImageView = findViewById(R.id.bgImageView);
}

private void initDataBindings() {
    int id = R.drawable.login_background;
    Utils.setImageToImageView(getApplicationContext(), bgImageView, id);
}

private void initActions() {
    forgotButton.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked Forgot Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    });

    createTextView.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked Create Account", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    });

    facebookLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked Facebook authentication - Not available yet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    });

    twitterLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked Twitter authentication - Not available yet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    });

    googlePlusLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked Google Plus authentication - Not available yet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    });

    loginButton.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    });

}

private void userlogin() {

    String email = emEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = emPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    if (email.isEmpty()) {
        emEmail.setError("Email Required");
        emEmail.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
        emEmail.setError("Please enter a valid email");
        emEmail.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    if (password.isEmpty()) {
        emPassword.setError("Password Required");
        emPassword.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            Log.d("Response", String.valueOf(task)); //view response
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, FeatureDashboardNewsDashboard1Activity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.createTextView:

            startActivity(new Intent(this, SignUpActivity.class));

            break;

        case R.id.loginButton:
            userlogin();

            break;

    }

}
```

}

I'm trying to navigate to the next activity

public class FeatureDashboardNewsDashboard1Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_feature_dashboard_news_dashboard1);

    initData();
    initUI();
    initDataBinding();
    initActions();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search,menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked "+ item.getTitle() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void initData() {

}

private void initUI() {

    // Init Toolbar
    initToolbar();

    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(item -> {

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.homeMenu) {
            loadFragment(new FeatureDashboardNewsDashboard1Fragment());
        }

        return true;
    });

    loadFragment(new FeatureDashboardNewsDashboard1Fragment());

}

private void initDataBinding() {

}

private void initActions() {

}

private void initToolbar() {

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.baseline_menu_black_24);

    if (toolbar.getNavigationIcon() != null) {
        toolbar.getNavigationIcon().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.md_white_1000), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    }

    toolbar.setTitle("News Dashboard 1");

    try {
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.md_white_1000));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("TEAMPS", "Can't set color.");
    }

    try {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("TEAMPS", "Error in set support action bar.");
    }

    try {
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("TEAMPS", "Error in set display home as up enabled.");
    }

}

private void loadFragment(FeatureDashboardNewsDashboard1Fragment fragment) {
    this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
            .commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

}

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".fragment.FeatureDashboardNewsDashboard1Fragment"
        tools:ignore="Instantiatable" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Adapter.FeatureDashboardNewsDashboard1CoverFlowPagerAdapter"
        tools:ignore="Instantiatable" />
    <activity android:name=".FeatureDashboardNewsDashboard1Activity" />
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".SignUpActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".SplashActivityLayout" />
    <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />`
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Log before using the if condition and see the response first i.e

```
 Log.d("Response",String.valueOf(task)); //view response
 if(task.isSuccessful()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, FeatureDashboardNewsDashboard1Activity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), task.getException().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: @ Hillarie-Kip, Thanks for your suggestion. I've tried this with still no resolution. code now updated above.

Comment: please provide the logs and what does is say after logging @DoAdventures

Comment: 2020-10-05 13:44:29.030 23696-23696/? E/doadventuresv3: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2020-10-05 13:44:29.055 23696-23715/? E/BehaviorCollectManager: Fail to acquire dataAnalyzerService...